# When installing SQL Server, "Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed."

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Brand new Windows Server 2008 R2 install handed over to us from Windows admin group. I try to run the SQL Server 2008 R2 install and get this error:

*Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.DebugBreak()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Setup.Setup.Main()**

The error happens almost immediately, so there isn't even a log file produced by the installer. I'm thinking there's a security setting I need to fix in the OS, but I have no idea where to begin.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you running install with elevated privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing from a file share?  Try installing using the actual install disc.

Comment: turns out the problem was that the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer doesn't work very well with .NET 4.0 installed on the machine. There are some config files that have to be modified to get it to work. I'll come back and post info on the workaround next week when I get back to the office.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. Needed to copy the installer from the file share to the local system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the security on the server had all Applications and .exe files as read-only/blocked.  Used https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/14/easily-unblock-all-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell/ to unblock all and the error went away.  .Net 4.0, 3.5 and earlier were already installed.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. When the link breaks, your answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question. Please include at least a summary so the answer can stand on its own. Thank you!